# Complete list of all Android resource folders?

Tags: android, resources

First I thought that I could find this list on the net, but I'm either looking for the wrong term or such list doesn't exist.

What I need is basically a cheat sheet of all predefined resource folders in an Android project. For example, a list could say something like this

- res/drawable - all graphics go here
- res/drawable-hdpi - all graphics of higher resolution go here
- res/layout - some-meaningful-description
- res/values - some-meaningful-description
- res/layout-land - some-meaningful-description
- etc.

I am really surprised that such list isn't easily found on the net. Whenever I need to add some resource I haven't used before, I have to look on the net for the correct naming (and I would rather look at the list of res folders).

Comment: Have you checked http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html. For each folder you can use combinations of the following tags small, normal, large, xlarge, nodpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi, land, port, long, notlong, and others.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

In the /res folder you can have:

- animator/ -XML files that define property animations.
- anim/ - XML files that define tween
  animations
- color/ - XML files that define a state list of colors.
- drawable/ - Bitmap files / Nine-Patches (re-sizable bitmaps) 
                     / State lists /  Shapes / Animation drawables /  Other drawables
- layout/ - XML files that define a user interface layout.
- menu/ - XML files that define application menus, such as an Options
  Menu, Context Menu, or Sub Menu.
- raw/ - Arbitrary files to save in their raw form.
- values/ - XML files that contain simple values, such as
  strings, integers, and colors.

  - arrays.xml for resource arrays (typed arrays).
  - colors.xml for color values
  - dimens.xml for dimension values.
  - strings.xml for string values.
  - styles.xml for styles.
- xml/ - Arbitrary XML files

Also see [Accessing  Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more specific device configurations (locale, dpi, size, aspect, orientation, etc)

Comment: If you provide internationalisation (i18n) in your app, with the exception of `strings.xml` which MUST be added to each directory where a language other than English is supported (e.g. values-ca, values-vi, etc), all other resource files under **values** directory DO NOT need to be replicated / copied across the different **values** directory. These resource files are: `arrays.xml`, `colors.xml`, `dimens.xml` and `styles.xml`.

Comment: @ChuongPham: Pretty sure the individual filenames are arbitrary.  The documentation only mentions "strings.xml" in the "example" section.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Never thought about it, but you are right.
You can always create a new project based on available samples projects in eclipse and see they have chosen to organize it.

You can see how one of my project is organized.
[my project in eclipse](http://img703.imageshack.us/i/73991397.png/)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that these folder layouts are not written in stone. One can create a folder tree in whatever manner one chooses. This is just the default tree created with IDEs such as Eclipse and is, as a result, the most popular and often consistent format. If you find another format to fit you better then you are free to use it. Just reference properly in your code.

Comment: This is untrue unless you want to start rewriting the build tools, since the resource folders are not directly referenced in code.