# Whats the meaning of having both values and xml directories?

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm trying to understand why it has been decided to have both `values` and `xml` subfolders in the `res` Android application folder.

While I can see the semantics differences between, say, `drawables` and `anim` and `values` (for those hold objects of different natures) I fail to see difference between `xml` and `values` for xml data seem to be values.

(And, moreover, 'xml' seem to describe the form of data representation not the nature of data (most of the res data are in the form of xml))

Could someone give an insight?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761406/complete-list-of-all-android-resource-folders

Comment: I'm downvoted because my question is... ? :)

Comment: Don't know, but I upvoted it cause I've had this question in mind since a long time :)

Comment: Another upvote to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.  Perfectly reasonable question.  The key to me is that XML and values are arbitrary.  Out of habit (because when I did my first project using embedded XML I didn't know about res/XML) I put my XML in res/raw since I know that Android never futzes with it.  I know of  no solid reason to use one or the other except to help manage your project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` should usually hold files that contain separate values not tied with each other, like `strings`, `dimens` or `colors`. `xml` should hold files that can be considered as a whole, like `app_widget_provider` or `search_provider` files. This is the only difference I can think of.